# Update a record in a SQL Server CE table using LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am building a class library for Windows Phone. As the title suggests, all I want to do is to update a record in a SQL Server CE table. All the methods I came across involve fetching the record from database, manually updating the values and then flushing changes back to the database.

Issue here is that, I'm building a library. So I don't know beforehand which columns are going to be there. So, manually updating values is out of question. I want something simpler like `UpdateOnSync` method which could be used as follows:

```
Contacts.UpdateOnSubmit(contctToUpdate);
```

Where `Contacts` is a table. Is this somehow possible? Apparently, SQLite for Windows Phone, Windows Azure, etc. have update methods and their style is pretty close to LINQ. How do I update I record without manually modifying values?

**Update 1:** I just ran following code for testing. It didn't work either!

```
//Get updated items from local to put them in cloud
var newLocalItems = (from TEntity p in localTable
                     where p.LastModified > currentTimeStamp
                     select p).ToList();
foreach (var localItem in newLocalItems)
{
    if (localItem.RemoteId == 0)
    {        
        localItem.LastSynchronized = DateTime.Now;                    
        connection.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Even after modifying the value manually, the rows in database are unmodified. Does the update work only when a single item is fetched?

Here's how I get connection:

```
public async void ConfigureSQLCE<T>(T mainDataContext) where T : DataContextBase
{           
    MainDB = mainDataContext; //MainDB is class level dynamic
}
```

And here's GetConnection method:

```
private async Task<DataContextBase> GetConnection()
{
    if (!MainDB.DatabaseExists())
    {
        MainDB.CreateDatabase();
    }
    return MainDB;
}
```

Then I obtain `connection` by `var connection = await GetConnection();`
The table mentioned above doesn't exist in the class `DataContextBase`. It rather exists in a class derived from it. How do I go about this situation now?

**Update 2:** Manually setting property like `localItem.LastSynchronized = DateTime.Now` started to work magically after I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the model.

Still, original question stands, how do I update item?

Comment: this code looks okay, can you add some more code which defines the scope of 'connection'

Comment: @db42 See the edit. The table I'm making updates in doesn't exist in `DataContextBase`, but it does exist in the `MainDB` which is derived from `DataContextBase`. So, when my `GetConnection` method returns, what does it return? Actuall `MainDB` or `MainDB` trimmed down to `DataContextBase`?